# Horizontal CSS Nav Padding differences in Firefox,IE9 vs Chrome, Opera

Tags: html, css, firefox, google-chrome

I have a weird problem on a CSS menu. There's a difference in padding applied by both 
Firefox & IE9 vs Chrome & Opera browsers. The space left after the last menu item at the end of the menu is different on both the browsers.
Please see the chrome.jpg and firefox.jpg inside zip file to see what I mean. 
I have also attached the source html file.

here is the zip file -
https://www.sugarsync.com/pf/D6612639_7394829_952554

**Chrome:**
[image]

**Firefox:**
[image]

Comment: You could get good responses if you put your HTML, CSS, etc into [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not padding but likely a difference in how the fonts are rendered in different browsers. Yeah that is pretty much impossible to solve unless you make the menu items fixed width. :)

The firefox version looks bolder (see it?!)... These are brainbreaking problems not fun to deal with but quite easy to explain.

Answer (score 0):

IE9/Firefox use a different technique to render text than Chrome/Opera do.

IE9/Firefox use DirectWrite, and so the text comes out ever so slightly wider, adding up to a few pixels difference over all the menu items.

Read more here: http://www.basschouten.com/blog1.php/font-rendering-gdi-versus-directwrite

And read this, particularly the "Hinting and spacing differences" section: http://blog.mozilla.com/nattokirai/2011/08/11/directwrite-text-rendering-in-firefox-6/

Short of setting a fixed width on each menu item (don't), you can't fix it. However, you don't *need* to fix it: a few pixels difference between browsers does not matter. Remember, the users of your site are only looking at it using *one* browser.